# Problem in parsing Arabic XML to read the word الله using iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, xml, nsxmlparser, arabic

Hi i am parsing an arabic XML file. The whole file is reading correctly. But when reading the word الله it does not read properly instead of that it reading it shows a box. Can any one help me In this issue.

Comment: When you mean 'reading', do you mean 'displaying'? If so, what are you using to display it? Are other arabic characters displaying correctly? Which font are you using to display them?

Comment: If you're trying to display an Arabic font, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481599/how-do-i-display-a-custom-arabic-font-in-my-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

In some operating systems, specially Windows, the word "Allah" is converted to a single character that may not be recognized by iOS fonts. Make sure that the XML file have the word "Allah" as letters "Alef", "Lam", "Lam" and "Haa" instead of a single character.